# mountall: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0

Tags: boot, mount, udev, shared-library

I don't know how to fix this. My system won't even get past the loading screen. When I press <kbd>F1</kbd> on the Ubuntu splash screen it shows me log with this message.

```
mountall: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0
```

I cannot find any answer for this problem. I am new user on Ubuntu so please tell me should I reinstall the whole system or do something else.

Comment: Could you please let us know which version of Ubuntu is it? --- On my system (Ubuntu 14.04.2 64-bit) I have `/sbin/mountall` which is linked to `libudev.so.1` (`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1`). It looks like this library is corrupted/missing on your system. --- You can boot from a [recovery media](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery), check and reinstall the `libudev` package. The procedure will be based on the section [Update Failure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure) more specific information could be provided for a specific version of Ubuntu.

Comment: My version is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit. Yes, you were right it got corrupted or missing somehow so I reinstalled from recovery terminal. Thank you very much!